# Threaded timer doesn't change as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to write a program/game where you have to defuse a bomb. it has a timer in it and it simultaneously checks if you cut the right wire for it to defuse. But when I run it, it prints out the time twice on the same line as the input, like this:

[image]

Only the first timer changes. Then the cursor jumps to a new line and if I type something it goes on that line (I want it to be on the same line). The code also doesn't `exit` when the timer has finished.

How can I fix this so that the timer is only on the first line, on the second line it asks for the input and it should print "The bomb went off" when the timer finishes?

```
#import time library for the timer
import time
#import thread library to run timer and wire function at the same time
from threading import Thread

def splitTime(sec):
    #splits seconds in minutes and seconds
    seconds = sec % 60 
    minutes = int((sec - seconds) / 60)
    if minutes == 0 and seconds == 0:
        print("00:00")
    else:
        if minutes < 10 and seconds < 10:
            print("0" + str(minutes) + ":" + "0" + str(seconds), end="\r")
        elif minutes < 10:
            print("0" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds), end="\r")
        elif seconds < 10:
            print(str(minutes) + ":" + "0" + str(seconds), end="\r")
        else:
            print(str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds), end="\r")

def timer():
    #the timer
    timeToSet = 10 
    while timeToSet >= 0:
        splitTime(timeToSet)
        time.sleep(1)
        timeToSet -= 1
    if timeToSet == 0:
        print("The bomb went off!")
        exit()

def wireFunction():
    color = input("which wire to cut?: ")
    if color == "red":
        print("The bomb has been defused!")
        exit()
    else: 
        print("The bomb went off!")
        exit()

wire = "red"
print("There are these wires: blue, red, green, black")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target = wireFunction).start()
    Thread(target = timer).start()
```

Comment: It does *not* write the time "as input". It's only the terminal that prints it this way but it shouldn't be included in what the user writes

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your problem about the timer not finishing at 0 is because you say `while timeToSet >= 0:` opposed to `while timeToSet > 0:`. Currently when it hits zero it's not exiting the while loop.